# Inverting pixels of an RGB image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I'm trying to invert the pixels of an RGB image. That is, simply subtracting the intensity value of each channel (red, green, blue) of each pixel from `255`.

I have the following so far:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('xyz.png')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
width, height = im.size

output_im = Image.new('RGB', (width,height))

for w in range(width):
    for h in range(height):
        r,g,b = rgb_im.getpixel((w,h))
        output_r = 255 - r
        output_g = 255 - g
        output_b = 255 - b
        output_im[w,h] = (output_r, output_g, output_b)
```

When I run the above script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_inverse.py", line 31, in <module>
    output_im[w,h] = (output_r, output_g, output_b)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 528, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __setitem__
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a vectorized operation if the image is a numpy array

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('xyz.png')
im = 255 - im
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a solution that would go with my code as I need to demonstrate the steps in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `img.putpixel` to assign the r,g,b,a values at each pixel-

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('xyz.png')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
width, height = im.size

output_im = Image.new('RGB', (width,height))

for w in range(width):
    for h in range(height):
        r,g,b = rgb_im.getpixel((w,h))
        output_r = 255 - r
        output_g = 255 - g
        output_b = 255 - b
        alpha = 1
        output_im.putpixel((w, h), (output_r, output_g, output_b, alpha))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert image to numpy array, and you can perform the operation on all 2-dimensional arrays in one line

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('my_image.png')

# Convert Image to numpy array
image_array = np.array(image)

print(image_array.shape)
# Prints something like: (1024, 1024, 4)
# So we have 4 two-dimensional arrays: R, G, B, and the alpha channel

# Do `255 - x` for every element in the first 3 two-dimensional arrays: R, G, B
# Keep the 4th array (alpha channel) untouched
image_array[:, :, :3] = 255 - image_array[:, :, :3]

# Convert numpy array back to Image
inverted_image = Image.fromarray(image_array)

inverted_image.save('inverted.png')
```